# I have created grid in which each row have button for approval request..on clicking button, cell value of that particular row must change

Tags: winforms, devexpress

Using Dev Express, Winform platform.
Here column UO_APR_STATUS must change from R to A only on clicking the button .But the button does not fire the event. Please help.

```
 public frmUnitOff()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
     

        BindingList<OM_UNIT_OFFER> result = new BindingList<OM_UNIT_OFFER>((from u in Program.projectModel.OM_UNIT_OFFERS orderby u.UO_SYS_ID where u.UO_APR_STS == "R" select u).ToList());
        this.gridControl1.DataSource = result;

      

    }

private void btn_Approve_ButtonClick(object senderDevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonPressedEventArgs e)
    {
     //Write code for grid cell value update on button click.  
    }
```

Comment: Is the button contained in the grid or separate? Do you have a delegate set for the button? If you put a breakpoint in the ButtonClick event handler, is it ever hit?

Comment: Button is inside the grid. Yes on clicking the Button click event  handler  it is working .But at the same time  it does not change the row cell value .Thank you

Comment: What happens inside the ButtonClick event handler? You need to post that code.

Comment: Action  that need to take place  is on button click , row cell value of UO_APR_STS  must change from  "R" to "A".So far, i have written inside the button click event handler  is

Answer (score 1):

Now working fine. I am sharing the code where I got the output may be helpful for someone .Thank you @brendon for your concern.

```
private void btn_Approve_ButtonClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonPressedEventArgs e)
    
    {
      
          
        gridView1.SetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, gridView1.Columns["UO_APR_STS"], "A");

        var a=  gridView1.GetFocusedRowCellValue("UO_SYS_ID");
        double ab = double.Parse(a.ToString());

        BindingList<OM_UNIT_OFFER> result = new BindingList<OM_UNIT_OFFER>((from u in Program.projectModel.OM_UNIT_OFFERS
                                                                            orderby u.UO_SYS_ID
                                                                            where u.UO_SYS_ID == ab
                                                                            select u).ToList());
        

        if (gridView1.PostEditor())
        {

        OM_UNIT_OFFER _unif = new OM_UNIT_OFFER();
        _unif.UO_APR_STS = "A";
        gridView1.FocusedColumn = gridView1.Columns["_unif.UO_APR_STS"];
        gridView1.UpdateCurrentRow();

        }
        
        gridView1.ShowEditor();
      
    }         




private void gridView1_RowUpdated(object sender, RowObjectEventArgs e)
    {            
     Program.projectModel.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So far, i have written inside the button click event handler  but it does not save into db.

private void btn_Approve_ButtonClick(object senderDevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonPressedEventArgs e)

{

```
gridView1.SetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, gridView1.Columns["UO_APR_STS"], "A");

var a = gridView1.GetFocusedRowCellValue("UO_SYS_ID");
double ab = double.Parse(a.ToString());


BindingList<OM_UNIT_OFFER> result = new BindingList<OM_UNIT_OFFER>((from u in Program.projectModel.OM_UNIT_OFFERS
                                                                    orderby u.UO_SYS_ID
                                                                    where u.UO_SYS_ID == ab
                                                                    select u.UO_SYS_ID));
if (gridView1.PostEditor())
{

    OM_UNIT_OFFER _unif = new OM_UNIT_OFFER();

    _unif.UO_APR_STS = "A";
}


gridView1.ShowEditor();
```

}